# SignalR postback causes jQuery actions to stop working

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I've got this widget on the screen, which changes the data contained within as well as its class based on some server-side and responds to mouse clicks on it. I'm using SignalR to notify multiple clients of updates simultaneously. The issue I'm having is that I've put everything including the markup in an Update Panel (otherwise I'd have to postback the entire page every time and that's an awful user experience) and after the first postback my picture with the "iconThing" ID no longer reacts to button clicks.

The original clicking functionality I was using was

```
$("#iconThing").click(function () {
    $(this).parent(".activity-pad").toggleClass("hidden-pad");});
```

After browsing through various online sources and stack overflow itself, I stumbled upon [SignalR Update Panel Only Works First Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675592/signalr-update-panel-only-works-first-time) which in theory should solve my issue - except for the fact that the new code I've added based on that no longer responds to clicks at all (I bet it's something fairly explanatory, but I'm rather new to javascript and jquery, so help would be more than appreciated)

```
 $(document).on("click", "#iconThing", function(){
        $(this).parent(".activity-pad").toggleClass("hidden-pad");});
```

The markup itself is (PadColorSetter is a serverside string, on which the output is based. It's been tested and is working (the visuals do change as intended) it's just the onclick functionality that seems to kill itself)

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="upActivityPadModule" IsUpdatePanel="true">
        <ContentTemplate>
<div class="activity-pad hidden-pad">
  <div class="icon <%# PadColorSetter %>" id="iconThing">
    Activity Pad
  </div>
  <div class="top <%# PadColorSetter %>">
  </div>
  <div class="middle <%# PadColorSetter %>">
    <div class="middle-content">
     <script type="text/javascript">
     // SignalR
     $(function () {
     // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
     var padUpdater = $.connection.activityPadHub;
     //$.connection.hub.start();

     // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
     padUpdater.client.ActivityPadRefresh = function () {

     __doPostBack('<%= upActivityPadModule.ClientID %>', '');
     };

     // Start the connection.
     $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
     // Call the ActivityPadRefresh method on the hub.
     padUpdater.server.ActivityPadRefresh();
     });
     });
</script>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom <%# PadColorSetter %>">
  </div>
</div>
        </ContentTemplate>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

EDIT.:

```
$("#iconThing").bind("click", function () {
```

instead of

```
$(document).on("click", "#iconThing", function(){
```

appears to react to the click. Unfortunately, only until a postback is done.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is struggling with the same issue, what saved me was:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function () {
    $("#iconThing").bind("click", function () {
        //$("#iconThing").click(function () {
        $(this).parent(".activity-pad").toggleClass("hidden-pad");
    });
});
```